# Moving 2D Array For Space Invaders Game

Tags: java, arrays, processing

So the title pretty much explains it all, recently I have learned about 2D arrays but I am a little confused on how to make the 2D array move correctly in this Space Invaders game I am creating.

Right now I have Aliens moving left to right (and vice versa), however, they don't all move down at the same time, they move down column by column. Anyone know where to edit the code?

Here is my code for the Aliens:

```
class Aliens {

  int x = 100, y = 75, deltaX = 1;

  Aliens (int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void drawAlien() {
    fill(255);
    rect(x, y, 25, 25);
  }

  void moveAlien() {
    x = x + deltaX;
    if (x >= width) {
      y = y + 20;
      deltaX = - deltaX;
    } else if (x <=0) {
      y = y + 20;
      deltaX = - deltaX;
    }
  }

  void updateAlien() {
    drawAlien();
    moveAlien();
  }
}
```

and my main class:

```
import ddf.minim.*;

//Global Variables
PImage splash;
PFont roboto;
Defender player;
Aliens[][] alienArray = new Aliens[15][3];
Missile missile;
int gameMode = 0;
int score = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 750);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  splash = loadImage("Splash.png");
  player = new Defender();
  for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
      alienArray[row][column] = new Aliens((row + 1) * 50, (column + 1) * 50);
    }
  }
  roboto = createFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 32);
  textFont(roboto);
}

void draw() {
  if (gameMode == 0) {
    background(0);
    textSize(75);
    text("Space Invaders", width/2, height/8);
    textSize(25);
    text("Created by Ryan Simms", width/2, height/4);
    textSize(45);
    text("Press SPACE to Begin", width/2, height - 100);
    image(splash, width/2-125, height/4 + 75);
  } else if (gameMode == 1) {
    background(0);
    score();
    player.updateDefender();
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row ++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
        alienArray[row][column].updateAlien();
      }
    }
    if (missile != null) {
      missile.updateMissile();
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == ' ') {
        if (missile == null) {
          missile = new Missile(player.x);
        }
      }
    }
    if (missile != null) {
      if (missile.y <= 0) {
        missile = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

void score() {
  textSize(20);
  text("Score: " + score, 40, 15);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    gameMode = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic flaw is in the `moveAlien()` method. You move the `x` position of an alien by a certain delta. If it is detected that the alien has passed some screen boundary (the `x >= width` and `x <=0` checks), you invert the delta to reverse the movement of the alien, and also update the `y` position to have it move down.

Since the aliens are oriented in vertical columns, one column will always reach such a boundary while the others haven't yet. So that column will go down, and also begin reverting its movement. The other columns will then "catch up" later. So not only do they move down per column, the columns will also end up moving through one another.

You'll have to implement some logic to have your aliens move as a block, by detecting when the rightmost remaining alien has reached the right boundary, or the leftmost remaining alien has reached the left boundary, and then doing an update on all aliens to move down.

The idea of having each alien have its own state, putting the logic for controlling it in the alien class and calling that is actually good object-oriented design. It just so happens that for Space Invaders, the aliens all affect one another because they move in a block. As a result, your design results in them having too much individuality. Perhaps you can add some class that maintains state for the invader array as a whole (such as the leftmost and rightmost column still having an alien, direction of the entire block), control that in your movement loop and have it update the alien's location in turn.

Comment: I was kind of hoping of an explanation on how to do this, or at least a point in the general direction

Comment: @Ryan I told you where the root to the problem is, and even provided a warning about how the columns will start moving across each other. If you want to learn how to program you'll have to think about how to refactor your code. Your question was where to edit the code. I answered that. Coding it for you would be of little value to your learning. SO isn't that kind of site.

Comment: I've only ever asked one other question on this site and people were happy enough to help me out and I could learn what needed to be done. I have spent a couple of hours previously trying to figure out what the problems is. I don't often like asking for help but when I do it'd be nice to at least show me what line I need to change. Do I need to make a 2D array in the alien class instead to make them all move? I am new to 2D arrays and I would get help from my university but I am off this week.

Comment: @Ryan I have told you where the problem is (in your `moveAlien()` method) and what the problem is: moving an alien down happens when it crosses a threshold (left or right edge), but that happens for one column at a time. If you've written the code you've shown us, the error in your reasoning should be clear from that. However, this isn't a one-line or even one-method fix, but requires some rethinking and restructuring of your program. As such I can't provide a code fix without doing your homework for you.

Comment: Also see: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason